# How to get only present connected Bluetooth device name in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying get the connected Bluetooth device name in android.

Done like below ,

```
mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

String name = mBluetoothAdapter.getName();

Log.d(TAG,"name--->"+name);
```

but I am getting my device name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android **[BluetoothManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager)**

following functions you can make use of :

> **getConnectionState** (BluetoothDevice device, int profile)

> **getConnectedDevices** (int profile) //get fetch connected device's info

Example :

```
BluetoothManager btManager = (BluetoothManager) 
mContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
List<BluetoothDevice> devices = 
btManager.getConnectedDevices(BluetoothProfile.GATT);
for(BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
    // you will get each device's info here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I trying to get the currently connected device name , not all connected device names.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `mac-address` of the connected device then you can get the device by

```
BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mac-address);
```

And to get the name of the connected device

```
String connectedDeviceName = device.getName()
```

Comment: receiving all near by BT device names, I trying to get only connected Bluetooth device name.